# Getting absolute position of elements inside fixed div container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a list of pages and a container and a list of links to every page,
i'm using the [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function of jquery to move to the desired page using the page's [offset().top](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) value and it works the first time but after that if I click another page's link the offset().top positon is not the same and it starts doing weird things...

Here's a code snippet that shows the issue

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #AFAFAF;">
 <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: white; width: 100px; height: 120px; z-index: 99">
  <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(1);">Go to page 1</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(2);">Go to page 2</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(3);">Go to page 3</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(4);">Go to page 4</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(5);">Go to page 5</a><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(6);">Go to page 6</a>
 </div>
 <div id="divContainer">
  <div id="fixedContainer" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
   <div id="pageContainer"
    style="margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; max-width: 800px; position: relative; overflow-y: scroll; transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;">
    <div id="page1" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightblue;">
    </div>
    <div id="page2" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightcoral;">
    </div>
    <div id="page3" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightcyan;">
    </div>
    <div id="page4" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;">
    </div>
    <div id="page5" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightgray;">
    </div>
    <div id="page6" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightgreen;">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>
  function goToPage(elementId) {
   $('#pageContainer').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#page' + elementId).offset().top
   }, 1200);
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The desired outcome would be moving seamlessly between pages,
without modifying the actual structure would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider `position()` instead of `offset()` and you should not do it on the fly but only once at the page load.

You can try like below:

```js
$("#pageContainer > div").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("offset",$(this).position().top);
})

function goToPage(elementId) {
  $('#pageContainer').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#page' + elementId).attr('offset')
  }, 1200);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #AFAFAF;">
  <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: white; width: 100px; height: 120px; z-index: 99">
    <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(1);">Go to page 1</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(2);">Go to page 2</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(3);">Go to page 3</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(4);">Go to page 4</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(5);">Go to page 5</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="goToPage(6);">Go to page 6</a>
  </div>
  <div id="divContainer">
    <div id="fixedContainer" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
      <div id="pageContainer" style="margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; max-width: 800px; position: relative; overflow-y: scroll; transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;">
        <div id="page1" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightblue;">
        </div>
        <div id="page2" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightcoral;">
        </div>
        <div id="page3" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightcyan;">
        </div>
        <div id="page4" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;">
        </div>
        <div id="page5" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightgray;">
        </div>
        <div id="page6" style="position: relative; height: 1200px; background-color: lightgreen;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> The `.position()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (specifically its margin box) **relative to the offset parent** (specifically its padding box, which excludes margins and borders). Contrast this with `.offset()`, which retrieves the current position relative to the document. When positioning a new element near another one and within the same containing DOM element, `.position()` is the more useful. <sup>[ref](https://api.jquery.com/position/)</sup>